# Can after hooks can be added to force kill a process from command line

Tags: java, shell, process, command-line-interface

I have a java package that takes long time to build. So if I want to stop the build in the middle when I know that it will not work in the expected way, I use `ctrl+C`. But there are some Database changes taking place, which will altered. So I want to create a way to kill the process where I can handle the database corrections will forcefully killing the build. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

A *build* system that updates a database? Strange idea. 
It also seems strange that building a single java package takes a lot of time.

Thus, two answers:

- on a first level, you would have to step back, and add some code somewhere that clearly understands the different build steps, and understand when things can be interrupted, and *how* to do that safely. And yes, if everything runs in one JVM, maybe shutdown hooks could help. But depending on context, they might not be reliable enough
- but then, that would mean invest even more energy into some *dubious* design. I would rather step back, and look at the goals that you intend to achieve using this strange setup. And then think up ways that require less "home made innovation".